# Relative path to CSS file for subdomains

Tags: php, html, css

I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong here.   I'm just trying to use the `CSS`files in `/css/` as a management point for the rest of the page and have tried `"../../css/test1.css"` and `"../css/test1.css"` for `relative paths` in my link `hrefs` but I can't get it to point from the `subdomains` correctly without supplying the `absolute paths (domain.com/css/test1.css, domain.com/css/test2.css, ect)` to the `css` files.  `index.php` in the root displays correctly but the `subdomains` do not.  I'm guessing my `relative path` syntax is wrong.  Any help is appreciated.  See image below for details.  Thanks in advance.

[image: Why isn't my CSS working?]

Comment: what error your getting?

Comment: subdomain or sub-directory?

Comment: Not working? Did you forget to clear your cache?

Comment: @Aravind - no error, just not pulling the styles in

Comment: @Phil it's a sub-domain, that's appears as a sub directory on my server

Comment: What exactly is the URL you use to access `public_html/subdomain/index.php`? Is it `domain.com/subdomain/index.php` or something else?

Comment: in browser go to developer tools and check if your css files are added as a part of application source. @hidefind

Comment: Use an absolute path. If that works it's a Server permission issue.

Comment: @Phil domain.com's index.php is located in public_html's root.  subdomain.domain.com is where I'm having trouble

Comment: That was not what `@Phiil` asked. Notice he's in the subdomain directory.

Comment: @PHPglue absolute path works, but relative will not.  All files are within public_html and permissions to them seem ok

Comment: HTTP paths are limited to the document root of the host / virtual host. If you're using Apache, you could try setting an [alias](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_alias.html#alias) in the `subdomain.domain.com` virtual host to point `/css` to the primary domain's `public_html/css` directory

Comment: There's your answer.

Comment: @PHPglue, sorry for the confusion, I've set the subdomain directory up as a subdomain - i should have mentioned that.

subdomain.domain.com is where I'm having problems calling css/test1-3.css

Comment: That's because your Sever at the subdomain level is unable to see files in the upper domain. If you feel you must use relative paths, consider HTML like `<base href='http://domain.com' />`.

Comment: @PHPglue that's nice alternative to server-side tweaks but OP would then need to keep in mind any links to `subdomain.domain.com` URIs would have to be fully qualified

Comment: `@Phil` makes a good point. All relative href's on the page would be based on your upper domain if you use the `<base />` tag the way I described.

Comment: I actually looked into supplying the base href but it broke other portions of my code doing so - so it sounds like I'll need to fix those to be able to use it.  bummer but if I know that's the way then I'll do what needs to be done.  thank you so much PHP and Phill

Comment: What you're trying to do is impossible, because the browser cannot read your filesystem. The sub-domain is the root folder for the site.

Answer (score 1):

Almost for-sure your server is not configured to serve files for the subs from outside their own directory (each sub gets a view of only their little sandbox, not the whole server--this is a good thing for security reasons!).  If you can, change your web server to have a /css path for the sub (syntax varies depending on web server).

Alternatively, you can try just creating a symlink (cd sub; ln -s ../css).  That may or may not be allowed by your server config, though.

Comment: You could also make your css a PHP script that just parrots the css you want.  Just make sure set your content-type correctly.

Comment: Definitely **not** a job for PHP (or any other application language). I'd say most (if not all) HTTP servers are quite capable of linking / aliasing / etc

Comment: all of you are awesome for assisting me and I'm very grateful.  I think you may be right BJ - I had to use absolute paths to get the images to work as well which seems to line up with your theory.  many many thanks to all the contributors here and your lightning fast responses.